# Java Script: TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTHead' of null, while printing table dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner at coding and I am trying to print a table dynamically in my HTML file. The following error appears: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createTHead' of null
    at generateTableHead3", where generateTableHead3 is my calling of function to print the header.

I have been trying to understand why this is happening to absolutely no avail for the last 4 hours.

I have other printed tables dynamically, and they all work. This code is copy-pasted from the original table which prints perfectly on the HTML, and so do other 2 tables created in the same JS file. And then, the third one doesn't. I created a separate html and js to test, and it still returns the error. What am I missing?

```
let header3 = ["Name", "No. Party", "% Party Votes"];

function generateTableHead3(table, array) {

    let thead = table.createTHead();
    let row = thead.insertRow(0);
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("th");
        cell.innerHTML = array[i];
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
}
function generateTable3(table, data) {
    for (let element of data) {

        let row = table.insertRow();
        let cell1 = row.insertCell();
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        let link = document.createTextNode(element['first_name'] + ' ' + (element['middle_name'] || '') + ' ' + element['last_name']);
        a.appendChild(link);
        a.href = element.url;
        a.title = link;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        cell1.appendChild(a);


        }
    }

let table3 = document.getElementById("least-loyal");
let data3 = Object.keys(array10LeastLoyal);
generateTableHead3(table3, header3);
generateTable3(table3, array10LeastLoyal);
```

Comment: The error comes from this line: `let thead = table.createTHead();` and simply means that `table` is `null`, so you can't call `createTHead()` on it. Since `table` is an argument you pass into `generateTableHead3`, and you called `generateTableHead3` with `table3` as the `table` argument, it must mean that `table3` is null when you call the function.

Comment: Did you check if a HTML element with the ID `least-loyal` is present?

Comment: A simple test would be to add `console.log(table3);` just after your `let table3 = document.getElementById("least-loyal");` line to verify that the table is being found.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thank you. Indeed, I have checked in the console, and yes, it says that table3 is null. But I don't get it why, the table tag is in the html with the proper id.

Comment: @RamizWachtler thanks for replying. Yes, I did check, I triple checked, all the ids of all the tables are correct in the html. and the tags for the table are also good. Which is why I don't understand the error.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I found it. It was a typo in the HTML. >_< and because of that, the table was being null. Thank you for helping me understand where to look. It was a stupid mistake on my part, but I learned how to read an error, for what is worth.